# Any options to prevent a rename command to move files from subdirectories to the parent directory after renaming?

Tags: rename, macos

I have following subdirectories in the parent directory ./

```
find . -type d|sort
.
./M1_DMSO_120h
./M1_DMSO_24h
./M1_GW4869_120h
./M1_GW4869_24h
./M2_DMSO_120h
./M2_DMSO_24h
./M2_GW4869_120h
./M2_GW4869_24h
./M3_DMSO_120h
./M3_DMSO_24h
./M3_GW4869_120h
./M3_GW4869_24h
find . -type f -maxdepth 2 |sort
./M1_DMSO_120h/GSM7073729_M1_DMSO_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M1_DMSO_120h/GSM7073729_M1_DMSO_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M1_DMSO_120h/GSM7073729_M1_DMSO_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M1_DMSO_24h/GSM7073723_M1_DMSO_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M1_DMSO_24h/GSM7073723_M1_DMSO_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M1_DMSO_24h/GSM7073723_M1_DMSO_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M1_GW4869_120h/GSM7073732_M1_GW4869_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M1_GW4869_120h/GSM7073732_M1_GW4869_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M1_GW4869_120h/GSM7073732_M1_GW4869_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M1_GW4869_24h/GSM7073726_M1_GW4869_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M1_GW4869_24h/GSM7073726_M1_GW4869_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M1_GW4869_24h/GSM7073726_M1_GW4869_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M2_DMSO_120h/GSM7073730_M2_DMSO_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M2_DMSO_120h/GSM7073730_M2_DMSO_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M2_DMSO_120h/GSM7073730_M2_DMSO_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M2_DMSO_24h/GSM7073724_M2_DMSO_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M2_DMSO_24h/GSM7073724_M2_DMSO_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M2_DMSO_24h/GSM7073724_M2_DMSO_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M2_GW4869_120h/GSM7073733_M2_GW4869_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M2_GW4869_120h/GSM7073733_M2_GW4869_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M2_GW4869_120h/GSM7073733_M2_GW4869_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M2_GW4869_24h/GSM7073727_M2_GW4869_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M2_GW4869_24h/GSM7073727_M2_GW4869_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M2_GW4869_24h/GSM7073727_M2_GW4869_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M3_DMSO_120h/GSM7073731_M3_DMSO_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M3_DMSO_120h/GSM7073731_M3_DMSO_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M3_DMSO_120h/GSM7073731_M3_DMSO_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M3_DMSO_24h/GSM7073725_M3_DMSO_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M3_DMSO_24h/GSM7073725_M3_DMSO_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M3_DMSO_24h/GSM7073725_M3_DMSO_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M3_GW4869_120h/GSM7073734_M3_GW4869_120h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M3_GW4869_120h/GSM7073734_M3_GW4869_120h_features.tsv.gz
./M3_GW4869_120h/GSM7073734_M3_GW4869_120h_matrix.mtx.gz
./M3_GW4869_24h/GSM7073728_M3_GW4869_24h_barcodes.tsv.gz
./M3_GW4869_24h/GSM7073728_M3_GW4869_24h_features.tsv.gz
./M3_GW4869_24h/GSM7073728_M3_GW4869_24h_matrix.mtx.gz
```

Now, I'd like to remove the header of each of these files so they look like as follows in each subdirectories ;

```
 barcodes.tsv.gz
 features.tsv.gz
 matrix.mtx.gz
```

I tried to use `rename`  as below to do this;

```
rename "s/M\d.+_//g"  M*/*
```

but rename will move renamed files to the parent diretory.

My not-so-elegant solution is using `for loop and rename` as follows;

```
for i in $(cat dir.name) ; do cd $i ; rename  "s/GSM\d.+_//g"  *.gz ; cd .. ;done
```

I am wondering if there is any **options** in `rename` to accomplish this without using `for loop` ?

My system:

```
sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.6
BuildVersion:       22G120
```

Comment: Try using `find . -type f -maxdepth 2 -execdir rename ... {} +`